# What kind of opportunities to perform this sql code

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

In this code I have 2 select that I use more times, there are a possibility to write into a variable or another way to perform this one?

```
Select  CASE WHEN (SELECT Sum(Menge-Geliefert) AS tReserviert FROM PendenzenZeilen INNER JOIN Pendenzen ON PendenzenZeilen.Buchungs_ID = Pendenzen.Buchungs_ID 
           WHERE Artikel_ID = Artikel.Artikel_ID AND Variante = ArtikelLager.Variante AND Pendenzen.Lagerort = 0 AND Pendenzen.Status > 1 and Pendenzen.Buchungstyp = 1) is null 
     THEN 0 
     ELSE (SELECT Sum(Menge-Geliefert) AS tReserviert FROM PendenzenZeilen INNER JOIN Pendenzen ON PendenzenZeilen.Buchungs_ID = Pendenzen.Buchungs_ID 
           WHERE Artikel_ID = Artikel.Artikel_ID AND Variante = ArtikelLager.Variante and Pendenzen.Lagerort = 0 AND Pendenzen.Status > 1 and Pendenzen.Buchungstyp = 1) END AS eReserviert, 

CASE WHEN (SELECT Sum(Menge-Geliefert) AS tBestellt FROM PendenzenZeilen INNER JOIN Pendenzen ON PendenzenZeilen.Buchungs_ID = Pendenzen.Buchungs_ID 
           WHERE Artikel_ID = Artikel.Artikel_ID AND Variante = ArtikelLager.Variante AND Pendenzen.Lagerort = 0 AND Pendenzen.Buchungstyp = 2) is null 
     THEN 0 
     ELSE (SELECT Sum(Menge-Geliefert) AS tBestellt FROM PendenzenZeilen INNER JOIN Pendenzen ON PendenzenZeilen.Buchungs_ID = Pendenzen.Buchungs_ID 
           WHERE Artikel_ID = Artikel.Artikel_ID AND Variante = ArtikelLager.Variante AND Pendenzen.Lagerort = 0 AND Pendenzen.Buchungstyp = 2) END AS eBestellt,

(ArtikelLager.Lagerstand 
- 
CASE WHEN (SELECT Sum(Menge-Geliefert) AS tReserviert FROM PendenzenZeilen INNER JOIN Pendenzen ON PendenzenZeilen.Buchungs_ID = Pendenzen.Buchungs_ID 
           WHERE Artikel_ID = Artikel.Artikel_ID AND Variante = ArtikelLager.Variante AND Pendenzen.Lagerort = 0 AND Pendenzen.Status > 1 and Pendenzen.Buchungstyp = 1) is null 
     THEN 0 
     ELSE (SELECT Sum(Menge-Geliefert) AS tReserviert FROM PendenzenZeilen INNER JOIN Pendenzen ON PendenzenZeilen.Buchungs_ID = Pendenzen.Buchungs_ID 
           WHERE Artikel_ID = Artikel.Artikel_ID AND Variante = ArtikelLager.Variante AND Pendenzen.Lagerort = 0 AND Pendenzen.Status > 1 and Pendenzen.Buchungstyp = 1) END 
+ 
CASE WHEN (SELECT Sum(Menge-Geliefert) AS tBestellt FROM PendenzenZeilen INNER JOIN Pendenzen ON PendenzenZeilen.Buchungs_ID = Pendenzen.Buchungs_ID 
           WHERE Artikel_ID = Artikel.Artikel_ID AND Variante = ArtikelLager.Variante AND Pendenzen.Lagerort = 0 AND Pendenzen.Buchungstyp = 2) is null 
     THEN 0 
     ELSE (SELECT Sum(Menge-Geliefert) AS tBestellt FROM PendenzenZeilen INNER JOIN Pendenzen ON PendenzenZeilen.Buchungs_ID = Pendenzen.Buchungs_ID 
           WHERE Artikel_ID = Artikel.Artikel_ID AND Variante = ArtikelLager.Variante AND Pendenzen.Lagerort = 0 AND Pendenzen.Buchungstyp = 2) END) AS eZumVerkauf  
from ((Artikel 
   inner join ArtikelLager on Artikel.Artikel_ID = ArtikelLager.Artikel_ID) 
   inner join ArtikelLieferanten on Artikel.Artikel_ID = ArtikelLieferanten.Artikel_ID) 
where ArtikelLager.Lager_ID = 0 and Artikel_Status = 0
order by Bezeichnung, Variante
```

also I need to use eZumVerkauf in where condition, thank you!!

Comment: I guess you are looking for solutions on "sql-server", can you please add the appropriate tag? Currently it is pointing to SQL & Server

Comment: does this code work?  don't Artikel and ArtikelLager have to be in your `from` clause?

Comment: You mean *optimize* this code? For one, I'd try to create a view or something for those `SELECT` statements that you keep using over and over and over again in your `CASE` statements....

Comment: This code work very good.. and I need Artikel, ArtikelLager and ArtikelLieferant table in from clause

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do your joins in an inner `select` with the most restrictive conditions, then work with the results.  For the inner `select`, try something like:

```
SELECT 
   z.Buchungs_ID, a.Artikel_ID, a.Variante          
   Menge-Geliefert as tReserviert, Lagerstand, p.Status, p.Buchungstyp
FROM 
   PendenzenZeilen z INNER JOIN 
   Pendenzen p ON 
   z.Buchungs_ID = p.Buchungs_ID INNER JOIN
   Artikel a on 
   p?.Artikel_ID = a.Artikel_ID INNER JOIN
   Variante v on
   a.Variante = v.Variante -- inner join ArtikelLieferant al on ??
WHERE 
   p.Lagerort = 0 AND 
   ((Status > 1 and p.Buchungstyp = 1) or p.Buchungstyp =2))
```

then you can apply your `case` conditions in an outer select (not sure I have this the way you need it as some conditions are missing):

```
Select  
CASE WHEN tReserviert is null  THEN 0 
     when Buchungstyp = 1 then Sum(tReserviert) END AS eReserviert, 

CASE WHEN tReserviert is null THEN 0 
     when Buchungstyp = 2 then Sum(tReserviert) END AS eBestellt,

(Lagerstand 
- 
CASE WHEN tReserviert is null THEN 0 
     when Buchungstyp = 1 then Sum(tReserviert) END 
+ 
CASE WHEN tReserviert is null THEN 0 
     when Buchungstyp = 2 then Sum(tReserviert ) end AS eZumVerkauf  
from (inner SELECT) s
```